# pymongo query returns value or not

Tags: pymongo

result = db.nps.find({"CUSTOMER_NAME": Account}, { "_id": 0 })

I want to check if the result is empty or not without iterating the results

for e.g:

if result:

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use [find_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) instead. find_one returns None if there is no result.